# Marcar los checkbox de permisos asociados a un rol

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una colección que contiene los IDs de una lista de permisos para un rol de usuario y necesito compararlos con el ID de los permisos para marcar un checkbox en caso de que sean iguales.

De esta forma poder editar el rol y poder ver con los checkbox marcados los permisos de ese rol.

Este es mi metodo edit para los roles.

```
public function edit($id)
{   
    $role = Role::find($id);
    $permissions = Permission::get();
    $id_permission = $role->permissions->pluck('id');
    

    return view('roles.edit', ['role' => $role,
                                'permissions'=> $permissions,
                                'id_permission'=>$id_permission]);
}
```

Si imprimo la coleccion de los permismos que es $id_permission obtengo lo siguiente:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]

En la vista tengo lo siguiente y es la parte en que no funciona como lo habia pensado:

```
@foreach ($permissions as $permission)
                  <li>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="permissions[]" value = "{{ $permission->id, null }}">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{$permission->name}} </label>
                    </div>
                    @if ($permission->id == 24 )
                      <br>
                      <h3>Permisos de cliente</h3>
                      <hr>
                    @endif
                  </li>
                  @endforeach
```

Básicamente lo que hago en esta parte es desplegar la lista de permisos disponibles.

Mi intención es marcar los permisos que ya han sido asociados a ese rol anteriormente y así poder editarlos con mayor claridad.

Como podría comparar la lista de los ID de los permisos asignados con el ID del permiso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente tu problema radica en verificar que un id esté dentro del array de permisos, si es así, significa que tu checkbox debe marcarse. Esto puedes lograrlo usando [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) de la siguiente manera:

```
@foreach ($permissions as $permission)
    ....
    <div class="form-check">
         <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" checked="{{ in_array($permission->id, $id_permission) ? 'true' : 'false' }}">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{$permission->name}} </label>
    </div>  
    ...
@endforeach
```

La lógica viene en esta parte del código:

```
in_array($permission->id, $id_permission) ? 'true' : 'false'
```

Dado que `in_array` comprueba si un valor existe, o no, en un array; si existe es porque debes marcar el checkbox con `checked="true"`, caso contrario retornas false.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Implemente el codigo tal cual me dijiste, pero se marcaban todos los checkboxes sin importar si no tenial el permiso. Me sirvio mucho tu ejemplo y acabe poniendolo de la siguiente forma: <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="permissions[]" value = "{{ $permission->id, null }}"
                          @if(in_array($permission->id, $id_permission) == true) checked @endif>

Answer (score 0):

Creas roles anidados de permisos y roles. Si el Rol tiene asignado el permiso, entonces añade la propiedad `checked` para que el chekbox aparezca marcado. Algo como esto:

```javascript
@if ($rol->hasPermissionTo($permiso->name)) checked @endif
```

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo aplicado al código de la pregunta:

```
 @foreach ($permisos as $permiso)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $permiso->name }}</th>
        <!--Fila de Roles-->
        @foreach ($roles as $rol)
           <td>
              <div class="form-check">
                 <!--Si el Rol tiene asignado el permiso, entonces true checkBox ✔-->
                 <input type="checkbox" name="roles[{{ $rol->name }}][{{ $permiso->name }}]" @if ($rol->hasPermissionTo($permiso->name)) checked @endif>

               </div>
            </td>
         @endforeach

   </tr>

  @endforeach
```

Comment: Parece que sería más valiosa si explicaras en mayor detalle el tema. Es una forma de enseñar.